# Prove that powerset is closed under symmetric difference

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $ H $ is a set, then $(\mathcal{P}(H), \Delta)$ is an abelian group. $\Delta$ being defined as $X \Delta  Y = ( X -  Y) \cup ( Y -  X)$

I managed to prove that $\Delta$ is associative, commutative, has an identity element and every element has an inverse, but I don't know how to prove that it's closed.

How can I do it?

Comment: $X\triangle Y\subseteq X\cup Y\subseteq H$.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $H$, then, of course, $X \triangle Y$ is a subset of $H$.

Comment: I can get to the point of $X\triangle Y\subseteq X\cup Y$, but I don't know how to prove that $X\cup Y \subseteq H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that for any $X, Y \in \mathcal P(H),\, X\Delta Y\in\mathcal P(H)$.

If we get rid of the powerset notation, the above is equivalent to:
$$\forall X, Y \subseteq H: X\Delta Y\subseteq H$$

Comment: I can get to the point of $X\triangle Y\subseteq X\cup Y$, but I don't know how to prove that $X\cup Y \subseteq H$

Comment: Use the definition of subset: Pick any $x \in X\cup Y$, prove that $x\in H$, given that $X, Y \subseteq H$.

Comment: Thank you very much!